# In JavaScript how do I/should I use async/await with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, async-await, xmlhttprequest

Full disclosure: I'd qualify myself as having intermediate JavaScript knowledge. So this is slightly above my experience level at this time.

I've got a Google Chrome Extension that does an AJAX request for a local `file:///` as soon as a page loads. After I get the response back from the request I use the returned code in several functions later on in my code. Most of the time I get the response back before my code that needs it runs. But sometimes I don't and everything breaks.

Now, I assume I could just throw all of the relevant code inside of the `xhr.onload` below. But that seems really inefficient? I have a lot of moving parts that rely on the response and it seems bad to put them all in there.

I've perused several articles related to async/await and I'm having trouble grasping the concept. I'm also not 100% positive I'm looking at this the right way. Should I even be considering using async/await?

Here is the code for my AJAX request.

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    code = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error("** An error occurred during the XMLHttpRequest");
  };
  xhr.send();
```

Let's say I've got a bunch of functions that need to fire afterwards later on in my code. Right now they just look like:

```
function doTheThing(code) {
  // I hope the response is ready.
}
```

What's the best way to approach this? FYI, the `Fetch` API isn't an option.

Here's a high level view of how my code is structured.

```
// AJAX request begins.

// ...

// A whole bunch of synchronous code that isn't dependant on 
// the results of my AJAX request. (eg. Creating and appending
// some new DOM nodes, calculating some variables) I don't want
// to wait for the AJAX response when I could be building this stuff instead.

// ...

// Some synchronous code that is dependant on both my AJAX 
// request and the previous synchronous code being complete.

// ...

// Some more synchronous code that needs the above line to 
// be complete.
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead? It's Promise-based from the start.

Comment: Putting code into a callback has absolutely no bearing on efficiency or performance.  It's just code, and a callback is just a callback. The code is either performant or not.

Comment: to use XMLHttpRequest with async/await, you'll need to make a Promise

Comment: Just call `doTheThing(code)` from inside the `onload` function.

Comment: @E.Sundin Fetch doesn't work with local `file:///` files which is what I need.
@JaromandaX That's what I figured. Having trouble getting that to work though.

Comment: @Pointy Does async/await serve no purpose to an AJAX request then?

Comment: `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar intended to make coding around Promise APIs simpler and cleaner. They have no performance impact; however a Promise-based API behaves, it behaves the same way when used via `async` and `await`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've edited my question above to give a brief high level view of how my code is currently structured. Would you still recommend your answer to me based on that?

Answer (score 92):

I usually do async/await like this:

```
async function doAjaxThings() {
    // await code here
    let result = await makeRequest("GET", url);
    // code below here will only execute when await makeRequest() finished loading
    console.log(result);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    doAjaxThings();
    // create and manipulate your DOM here. doAjaxThings() will run asynchronously and not block your DOM rendering
    document.createElement("...");
    document.getElementById("...").addEventListener(...);
});
```

[Promisified xhr function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr) here:

```
function makeRequest(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Like what it says, you need to put any `await` on async function. Just add `async` before the `function` text.

    `async function doTheThing(code) {
        let result = await makeRequest("GET", url);
        console.log(result);
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've edited my question above to give a brief high level view of how my code is currently structured. Would you still recommend your answer to me based on that?

Comment: I just updated my example. But if you want your 2 or more independent tasks to run in parallel (asynchronously), and run some other code only after all the tasks is done, check out Promise.all(). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @ThắngTrầnXuân If I could upvote your answer every day, I would!!!  You have just ended the most frustrating development session I have experienced in years! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it. You run a promise without setting the callbacks, plus you simply move the async nature of the promise to the outer function `doAjaxThings`. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @PJ_Finnegan Promises do not have callback, but I'm assuming you are talking about `then()` chain syntax. You can combine `makeRequest()` with a `then()` to avoid the need for creating `doAjaxThings()` function.

Comment: @Thắng Trần Xuân the `then()` arguments are usually the positive and negative callbacks, anyway you don't need any of this complications, the comments of Pointy and 4castle on the OP are spot on.

Answer (score 32):

I create a promise for the XHR. Then simply use `await` inside an `async` function to call it.

```
function getHTML(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.response.documentElement.innerHTML);
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}

async function schemaPageHandler(){
    try {
        var parser = new window.DOMParser();
        var remoteCode = await getHTML('https://schema.org/docs/full.html');
        var sourceDoc = parser.parseFromString(remoteCode, 'text/html');
        var thingList = sourceDoc.getElementById("C.Thing");
        document.getElementById("structured-data-types").appendChild(thingList);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching remote HTML: ", error);
    }              
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive example. I am not so sure about the reject() inside onload method. What is for sure, if you really want to handle all errors there should be onerror handler. But I didn't find definitive answer for if onload is fired for cases other than those ending with 2xx status (OK). [There are tests saying that it does not happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19247992/3273963), but on the other hand in first example [in this docs, they do check status](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: Why using DOMParser here? When you used `xhr.responseType = 'document';` the `xhr.response` is already of type HTMLDocument. If you instead resolve with `resolve(xhr.response)` then you'll get directly what you're now getting to `sourceDoc` Seems to me now you're DOM parsing in XHR then stringifying (innerHTML) the result and again DOM parsing it. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 16):

You get two options,

first is to use newer `fetch` api which is promise based, with with you can do

```
let response = await fetch(url);
response = await response.json();; // or text etc..
// do what you wanna do with response
```

Other option if you really want to use XMLHttpRequest is to promisify it

```
let response = await new Promise(resolve => {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", url, true);
   xhr.onload = function(e) {
     resolve(xhr.response);
   };
   xhr.onerror = function () {
     resolve(undefined);
     console.error("** An error occurred during the XMLHttpRequest");
   };
   xhr.send();
}) 
// do what you wanna do with response
```

possible full solution

```
(async () => {
   let response = await new Promise(resolve => {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", url, true);
      xhr.onload = function(e) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function () {
        resolve(undefined);
        console.error("** An error occurred during the XMLHttpRequest");
      };
      xhr.send();
   }) 
   doTheThing(response)
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, `fetch` doesn't allow `file:///` which is what I need. I'll try your `XMLHttpRequest` option and see if that works out for me.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @jkupczak you need to have this bits inside an async function eg: `async function fn () {}`, if you are doing this in the top level, you can put the code into a async IIFE `(async function fn() {})()`

Comment: When you say `// do what you wanna do with response`, how do I do that? I've got a function later on that I only want to fire once the response comes back. I don't know how to code that.

Comment: @jkupczak when i write `// do what you wanna do with response`, the response is already there, you can just call your function there, for example, replace `// do what you wanna do with response` with `doTheThing(response)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've edited my question above to give a brief high level view of how my code is currently structured. Would you still recommend your answer to me based on that?

Comment: not completely, i would move the block that is not dependent on the result, to execute while waiting for the result

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it using the following function:

```js
const makeRequest = (method, url, data = {}) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve({
      status: xhr.status,
      response: xhr.responseText
    });
    xhr.onerror = () => resolve({
      status: xhr.status,
      response: xhr.responseText
    });
    if (method != 'GET') xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    data != {} ? xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data)) : xhr.send();
  })
}

const test = async() => {
  console.log("Starting request ...")
  let request = await makeRequest("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  console.log("status:", request.status)
  console.log("response:", request.response)
}
test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for example create an asynchronous class to use instead of the original one. It lacks some methods but it can serve as an example.

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";
    
    var xhr = Symbol();
    
    class XMLHttpRequestAsync {
        constructor() {
            this[xhr] = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        open(method, url, username, password) {
            this[xhr].open(method, url, true, username, password);
        }
        send(data) {
            var sxhr = this[xhr];
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var errorCallback;
                var loadCallback;
                
                function cleanup()  {
                    sxhr.removeEventListener("load", loadCallback);
                    sxhr.removeEventListener("error", errorCallback);
                }
                
                errorCallback = function(err) {
                    cleanup();
                    reject(err);
                };
                
                loadCallback = function() {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                };
                
                
                sxhr.addEventListener("load", loadCallback);
                sxhr.addEventListener("error", errorCallback);
                
                
                sxhr.addEventListener("load", function load() {
                    sxhr.removeEventListener("load", load);
                    resolve(sxhr.response);
                });
                sxhr.send(data);
            });
        }
        set responseType(value)
        {
            this[xhr].responseType = value;
        }
        setRequestHeader(header, value) {
            this[xhr].setRequestHeader(header, value);
        }
    }
    
    addEventListener("load", async function main() {
        removeEventListener("load", main);


        var xhra = new XMLHttpRequestAsync();
        xhra.responseType = "json";
        xhra.open("GET", "appserver/main.php/" + window.location.hash.substring(1));
        console.log(await xhra.send(null));
        
    });
    
}());
```