# Async mixed with standard callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have just started to learn `Promise`s in Javascript, and happened upon `async/await`.

In my understanding, if I specify a function, to be `async`, javascript will always wrap the content of my function and return a `Promise` instead of whatever I am returning.

Let's presume the following scenario:

```
async function httpRequest() {
   oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
      return this.responseText;
   });

   oReq.open("GET", "http://some.url.here");
   oReq.send();
}

httpRequest().then(function(httpResult) {
    console.log(httpResult);
});
```

Am I correct in assuming, that the above situation will not work, as `httpRequest()` is not returning anything, the callback of `XMLHttpRequest` returns something only, thus my result will most likely be `undefined`?

If yes, how would I be able to fix `httpRequest()` so it will work in an `async/await` scenario?

Comment: `httpRequest()` doesn't need to be marked `async` because it isn't `await`ing anything. If you return the asynchronous operation, then you can do `await httpRequest()` in a separate `async` function.

Comment: it's marked as `async` so that I can `then` it in the next line. I wanted to use the languages functionality, that it wraps my function as a `Promise` automatically, instead of me having to return a `Promise`

Comment: You don't need `async`  to use `then()`, you just need to return a promise in one way or another. You can either return the promise, or if you prefer to keep it `async`, return the *awaited* promise (essentially taking a promise, unwrapping it with `await`, and then re-wrapping it).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [In JavaScript how do I/should I use async/await with XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969495/in-javascript-how-do-i-should-i-use-async-await-with-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is an async function that performs an async operation, where that operation does *not* use promises. This means that you need to setup a function that manages and returns a promise explicitly. You don't need the `async` keyword here, since you want to explicitly `return` a `Promise` that you create, and not a promise created for you by the async keyword (which you cannot directly manage).

```
function httpRequest() {

   // Return a promise (this is what an async function does for you)
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
     oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {

        // Resolve the promise when the async operation is complete.
        resolve(this.responseText);
     });

     oReq.open("GET", "http://some.url.here");
     oReq.send();
   };
}
```

Now that the function explicitly returns a promise, it can be `await`ed just like an `async` function. Or used with `then()` like any promise.

```
async function someFunction() {
  // await
  const awaitedResponse = await httpRequest();
  console.log(awaitedResponse);

  // or promise chain
  httpRequest().then(responseText => console.log(responseText));
};
```

Comment: `You can't actually use the async keyword here, since you nee to actually return a Promise.` - well you can still certainly use the async keyword and also return the promise, it would just be redundant

Comment: _Yo dawg, I heard you like promises. So I returned a promise that resolves a promise so you can async while while you async._ That is to say, sure you technically could. But that would not be a good thing to do :)

Comment: Promises auto-unwrap - `.then()` and `await` both automatically follow promise chains so it's practically no difference aside from being redundant

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you are trying to write an `async` function without having anything in that function to await. You use async/await when there is some asynchronous-ness in the code, while in yours, there isn't.

This is an example that might be useful:

```
const getItemsAsync = async () => {
    const res = await DoSomethingAsync();
    return res.items;
}

const items = await getItemsAsync();
```

As you can see, `DoSomethingAsync` is an asynchronous function I await the result for, which is `res`. At that point, the code will pause. Once the promise will be resolved, the code will resume and therefore will return `res.items`, which means that `items` will actually contain the result of the async function.

Also, async/await is just a spacial syntax that makes the code more readable, by giving it a more synchronous form (not substance).

If you really want to make it asynchronous, you can promisify your synchronous code in order to make it return a promise to await, that will then be either resolved or rejected.