# How can I print the "PUT" and "POST" method at the same time?

Tags: javascript, http, request

The function written to the bottom of the two functions works but the other one does not work. I am not getting an error message either. I think the transaction is taking place but nothing has been written. How can I get both to be written to the console? I'll put the console's printout below. Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
class Request {
    constructor() {
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    }

    post(url, data, callback) {
        this.xhr.open("POST", url)
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        this.xhr.onload = () => {
            if (this.xhr.status === 201) {
                callback(null, this.xhr.responseText)
            } else {
                callback("Hata", null)
            }
        }
        this.xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    }

    put(url, data, callback) {
        this.xhr.open("PUT", url)
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        this.xhr.onload = () => {
            if (this.xhr.status === 200) {
                callback(null, this.xhr.responseText, callback)
            } else {
                callback("Hata", null)
            }
        }
        this.xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    }
}

const request = new Request()



request.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums", {
    userId: 9,
    title: "Thriller"
}, function (error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})

request.put("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/9", {
    userId: 2,
    title: "Thriller"
}, function (error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

```
// Console Print
{
  "userId": 2,
  "title": "Thriller",
  "id": 9
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only creating one `Request` object, named `request`. The first call to `request.post()` uses `this.xhr` to perform a POST, but before that async process finishes, you're calling `request.put()` which performs a PUT, effectively ignoring the previous POST.

A simple way to resolve this is by creating two `Request` objects:

```
const request = new Request()
const request2 = new Request()

request.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums", {
    userId: 9,
    title: "Thriller"
}, function (error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})

request2.put("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/9", {
    userId: 2,
    title: "Thriller"
}, function (error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

You could also refactor your code to use `fetch()` instead. Other possible solutions: [In JavaScript how do I/should I use async/await with XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969495/in-javascript-how-do-i-should-i-use-async-await-with-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 1):

You should use your xhr once, not multiple times. To fix this, simply call `const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` in each method you need it.